# Determining which field Mongo found a $text $search match on

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo (2.6.4) and I understand that you can only have one text index per collection.

I can include several fields in the index and weight them, but is there any way to determine which field(s) it found a match on?

Answer (score 0):

As at MongoDB 3.0, [field weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) can be used to set the relative significance of fields in a document when calculating a relevance score, but there is no metadata in the return results to indicate which field(s) matched.

Comment: I think [SERVER-13532: Provide highlighting of results from full text search](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13532) in the MongoDB issue tracker is a feature suggestion which would fit your use case. If so, I would upvote/watch this issue via Jira. If not, feel free to create a new issue with alternative suggestions (NB: issue should be in the SERVER project with the "Text Search" component).